# Is there a format specifier that always means char string with _tprintf?

Tags: windows, printf, tchar, format-specifiers

When you build an app on Windows using `TCHAR` support, `%s` in `_tprintf()` means `char *` string for Ansi builds and `wchar_t *` for Unicode builds while `%S` means the reverse.

But are there any format specifiers that always mean `char *` string no matter if it's an Ansi or Unicode build? Since even on Windows UTF-16 is not really used for files or networking it turns out to still be fairly often that you'll want to deal with byte-based strings regardless of the native character type you compile your app as.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `h` modifier forces both `%s` and `%S` to `char*`, and the `l` modifier forces both to  `wchar_t*`, ie: `%hs`, `%hS`, `%ls`, and `%lS`.

Comment: Is this specific to MSVC? I just noticed this warning from gcc on Ubuntu 10: `warning: use of ‘h’ length modifier with ‘s’ type character`

Comment: No, it is not specific to MSVC, some other compilers support the `h` and `l` modifiers for the `s` type as well. I guess gcc is not one of them.

Comment: I have just tried this with gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4) 4.5.2 -- it works, sort of.

Comment: According to [this interesting page](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/FIO47-C.+Use+valid+format+strings), %hs is not a valid modifier in general and is considered insecure. I know that it works for MSVC with and without unicode, but clang generates a [-Wformat] warning, complaining that "length modifier 'h' results in undefined behavior or no effect with 's' conversion".

Comment: Again, it appears to be compiler specific. Some compilers support it (BCC, VC++), some do not (GCC).

Answer (score 1):

This might also solve your problem:

```
_TCHAR *message;
_tprintf(_T("\n>>>>>> %d") TEXT(" message is:%s\n"),4,message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily write something like this:

```
#ifdef _UNICODE
#define PF_ASCIISTR    "%S"L
#define PF_UNICODESTR  "%s"L
#else
#define PF_ASCIISTR    "%s"
#define PF_UNICODESTR  "%S"
#endif
```

and then you use the `PF_ASCIISTR` or the `PF_UNICODESTR` macros in your format string, exploiting the C automatic string literals concatenation:

```
_tprintf(_T("There are %d ") PF_ASCIISTR _T(" over the table"), 10, "pens");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found, that '_vsntprintf_s' uses '%s' for type TCHAR and works for both, GCC and MSVC.
So you could wrap it like:

```
int myprintf(const TCHAR* lpszFormat, va_list argptr) {
    int len = _vsctprintf(lpszFormat, argptr); // -1:err
    if (len<=0) {return len;}
    auto* pT = new TCHAR[2 + size_t(len)];
    _vsntprintf_s(pT, (2+len)*sizeof(TCHAR), 1+len, lpszFormat, argptr);
    int rv = printf("%ls", pT);
    delete[] pT;
    return rv;
}
int myprintf(const TCHAR* lpszFormat, ...) {
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, lpszFormat);
    int rv = myprintf(lpszFormat, argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
    return rv;
}



int main(int, char**) { return myprintf(_T("%s"), _T("Test")); }
```