# Mapping format specifiers when Unicode is defined in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, format-specifiers, tchar

> Mapping format specifier `%s` to `%ls` when `_tprintf()` is mapped to `wprintf()`?

I am using the `_T()` macro for mapping strings to either ASCII or Unicode, depending on whether `_UNICODE` is defined.

However, a call like `_tprintf("%s", _T("text string"))` is causing me trouble, because of inconsistent types when `_UNICODE` is defined.

I see that `%ls` should be used for Unicode strings.

How can `%s` be mapped directly to `%ls` when `_UNICODE` is defined? Is there some fancy function like `_T()?`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/5669173/166389 says that `%s` should match the behaviour of `_T()` already, and gives the formula to override that behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> However, a call like `_tprintf("%s", _T("text string"))` is causing me
>   trouble, because of inconsistent types when `_UNICODE` is defined.

You should use the **`_T()`** decorator also for the first string literal (i.e. the format specifier string) of `_tprintf()`:

```
// NOTE: _T("%s"), not just "%s"
//
_tprintf(_T("%s"), _T("text string"));
```

This is expanded in ANSI builds to:

```
printf("%s", "text string"); // %s maps to char* ANSI string
```

and in Unicode builds to:

```
wprintf(L"%s", L"text string"); // %s maps to wchar_t* Unicode string
```

Comment: What about the %ls specifier then? Is %s enough for Unicode?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: In Unicode builds, `%s` maps to `wchar_t*` Unicode strings. In ANSI builds, `%s` maps to `char*` ANSI strings. It's as simple as that. Or am I missing something from your question?

Comment: Then what are the specifiers %ls and %S used for? The %s specifier is just interpreted as Unicode in the context of wprint(), while it is being interpreted as ASCII in the context of printf()? Or is the compiler doing something special?

Comment: Also, is _T() and _tprintf() Windows specific?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: Yes, `_T()` and `_tprintf()` are Windows specific (as is  the so called "TCHAR model" of which they are a part of). In modern C++/Win32 code, I'd suggest just using Unicode, and avoid the whole complexity of the TCHAR model (which is for back compatibility with obsolete ANSI builds).

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: In Windows (MSVC): **`%s`** is mapped to the "natural" string type, i.e. to `char*` strings in printf and to `wchar_t*` strings in wprintf. **`%S`** is mapped to the "opposite" string type, i.e. `wchar_t*` in printf and `char*` in wprintf. **`%ls`** always maps to `wchar_t*` strings in both printf and wprintf.

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: You're welcome. MSDN and several years of Win32/C++ experience :)

Comment: I know this is off-topic, but why is it called Win32 and not Win64? Almost every OS is 64-bit, and we don't write 32-bit software?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: Historical reasons? :)

Comment: So it is actually 64-bit functionality in Win32, or is it both 64 and 32-bit? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to not use `_tprintf` but to use `std::wcout`.

1. `wcout` supports both ansi characters and `wchar_t` characters
2. `wcout` is safer then `XXXprintf` because it "knows" what kind of parameters it should print (avoid fiascos like `printf("%s",'a');`)
3. its portable while `_tprintf` is not
4. it's polymorphic and can work with other streams (like `fstream` and such) , `_tprintf` is not.

the only cons of `xxxcout` is that it tends to bloat the executable a bit and is a bit slower from the `printf` family , but I really dought it will be any real con in your app.

ditch the `printf` like functions in favor of C++ streams.

Comment: So wcout prints both ASCII and Unicode without problems? Why use cout then? Does wcout gets mapped to something like _tprintf() if _UNICODE is defined?

Comment: @NicolasLykkeIversen: "*Why use cout then?*" Because much of the non-Microsoft world uses UTF-8, and their `wchar_t` is a full 4 bytes.

Comment: `does wcout gets mapped to something like _tprintf() if _UNICODE is defined?` it uses overloading which is a C++ mechanism to accomplish general code (together with many others)

Comment: So if I have an ASCII string and a Unicode string in the same C++ program, then wcout applied to those strings like wcout << produces the right output?

I just saw some Stackoverflow answer, where a new variable tcout was defined as cout or wcout, depending on whether _UNICODE was defined. This is not neccessary, I see, because of wcout?

Comment: exactly , this : `std::wcout<< "hello " << L"world"; ` works fine without any problems

Comment: Also, are all the _T() and _tprintf() functionality only in place for those programming pure C?

Comment: Yes! C++ is too awsome for this sh*t